# Nginx reverse proxy for image server returns only html header

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I use Nginx to do reverse proxy for image server. (I am Nginx newbie).

To get the image from the original server we need to pass a token so the orignal url looks like this

http://www.myphoto.com/htm/GetDocumentAPI.aspx?F=TRX&DocID=15-551703&token=726gxJexU69LsQplDw@a.gIyDnVTtd0@LbcGe47Ku4*

and the response headers

```
Cache-Control →private
Content-Length →2653278
Content-Type →image/jpeg; charset=utf-8
Date →Wed, 10 May 2017 16:20:29 GMT
Server →Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version →4.0.30319
X-Powered-By →ASP.NET
content-disposition →inline;filename="15-551703.jpg"
```

My Nginx server:

```
location ~ ^/big/(.+) {
 proxy_pass http://www.myphoto.com/$1;
}
```

When I try to get image from my server

http://localhost/big/htm/GetDocumentAPI.aspx?F=TRX&DocID=15-551703&token=726gxJexU69LsQplDw@a.gIyDnVTtd0@LbcGe47Ku4*

Instead of the image I get:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

and the response:

```
Cache-Control →private
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Encoding →gzip
Content-Type →text/html; charset=utf-8
Date →Wed, 10 May 2017 16:07:08 GMT
Server →nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Transfer-Encoding →chunked
X-AspNet-Version →4.0.30319
X-Powered-By →ASP.NET
```

Changing the content type didn't work too

Comment: you have `htm` twice in the URL - is that a typo in the question?

Comment: Unfortunately that was typo